# google cloud functions httpsError not being thrown correctly

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to throw an error from an httpscallable. I have the error bubbling all the way up to the top level, I see the `"throwing https error"` in the console log, but for some reason no data is returned to the client.

The return is `{data:null}`

My code looks as follows

```
exports.checkin = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    checkin.checkin(data, context)
    .then(result => {console.log("returning",result); return result})
    .catch(error => {console.log("throwing https error"); 
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", (error.error_code) ? error.error_code : error.code, error.message);});
```

});

In the log I see:

```
- throwing https error checkin 
- Unhandled rejection checkin 
- Error: no_creditcard_for_charge
    at HttpsError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:74:9)
    at checkin.checkin.then.catch.error (/user_code/index.js:65:11)
```

line 65 is the "throw" line

Comment: What's in the log in the console?

Comment: @DougStevenson - updated the question with log statements

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that throwing an exception inside a `catch` callback doesn't propagate the same error to the promise returned by `catch`.  The [documentation for callables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) states:

> To ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a
>   callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an
>   instance of functions.https.HttpsError

In your case, you like need to return a promise rejected with an HttpsError.  I think this means you need to return the HttpsError object instead of throwing it out of the catch callback:

```
exports.checkin = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    checkin.checkin(data, context)
    .then(result => {console.log("returning",result); return result})
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("throwing https error"); 
        return new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument",
            error.error_code ? error.error_code : error.code, error.message);
     });
});
```

Comment: return new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument",
            error.error_code ? error.error_code : error.code, error.message); worked